# Why doesn't module openpyxl exist?

Tags: python, powershell, openpyxl

I am on Windows and have done `pip3 install openpyxl`.
I have also gotten "Requirement already satisfied: openpyxl in..."

However when I try to run a script that imports openpyxl, it gives:
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl**.

[image]

I have tried `python -m pip install openpyxl` and `python3 -m pip install openpyxl`. Openpyxl is then installed, but when I run the script, the same error above is given.

`pip show openpyxl` shows that it is already installed.

Is there something I am missing?
To note: there is an [(unknown)] beside my username in Powershell terminal that I am unable to remove.

`python -m pip install openpyxl` yields:
[image]

`where pip` and `where python` on cmd yields:
[image]

Update:
Uninstalled all versions of python, reinstalled 3.10 via python.org.
Reinstalled openpyxl, worked:
[image]

Comment: What is the output of `python -m pip install openpyxl`? "It does not work" is not enough information to identify the problem.

Comment: Run `where python` and `where pip` in cmd they may be different installations.

Comment: @AhmedAEK There is no `where` command in Powershell. The equivalent would be `Get-Command`

Comment: `Get-Command pip` and `Get-Command python`

Comment: @AbirbhavG. It gives "requirement already satisfied", but running the script gives the same error where the openpyxl module is not found

Comment: @AhmedAEK I think they are different installations, but what does this imply?

Comment: Looks like you have two pythons installed.  One via the windowsStore and one directly.  When working on windows machine, I tend to install Anaconda and be done with it.

Comment: Just uninstall them both then install one from python.org and check the mark to add it  to your PATH, avoid python3.11 now as openpyxl won't work on it, it's still new.

Comment: @WombatPM I have already installed Anaconda Navigator, but there doesn't seem to be python? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Realised I had many versions of Python installed in different directories, which messed with the pip installation of openpyxl.
Uninstalled them all and reinstalled Python 3.10, with pip in the same directory.
Reinstalled openpyxl, worked.
[image]